# Exchanging supremum and expectation

Tags: expectation, supremum-and-infimum

Consider a real-valued random variable $X_i$ defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, P)$.

Let  $m(X_i;\theta)$ be a random function which depends on the parameter $\theta \in \Theta \subseteq \mathbb{R}$.

(*) Suppose that for every sufficiently small open interval $(a,b) \in \Theta$ $E_P(\sup_{\theta \in (a,b)}m(X_i;\theta))<\infty$.

Define $\Theta_0:=\{\theta_0 \in \Theta \text{ s.t. } E_P(m(X_i; \theta_0))=\sup_{\theta \in \Theta}E_P(m(X_i; \theta))\}$

> I want to show that (*) implies that $E_P(m(X_i; \theta_0))<\infty$
>   $\forall \theta_0 \in \Theta_0$

I think that one way to proceed is by exchanging expectation and supremum but I'm not quite sure.

Comment: **Hint:** If $\theta_0\in\Theta_0$ then $m(X_i;\theta_0)\le \sup_{\theta\in(a,b)}m(X_i;\theta)$, and the latter satisfies $E_P(\sup_{\theta\in(a,b)}m(X_i;\theta))<\infty$ by hypothesis. [Technical point: Is $\theta\mapsto m(x,\theta)$ assumed to be continuous? Otherwise the measurability of $\sup_{\theta\in(a,b)}m(X_i;\theta)$ is an issue.]

Comment: Thanks. Why is it the case that "if $\theta_0 \in \Theta_0$ then $m(X_i;\theta_0)\leq \sup_{\theta \in [a,b]} m(X_i;\theta)$"?

Comment: It's actually true for any $\theta_0\in\Theta$, by the definition of "$\sup"$ (least upper bound).